# Copy formula down column, but skipping a row here and there

Tags: excel

So I have a formula that pulls data from another sheet and sums it. I want to pull this formula down the column, but I need to skip every eighth row. I need the formula to only increment by one as it jumps this row. Is there a quick way to accomplish this?

EDIT: To clarify, if cell A7 has formula =SUM(C3,H3) then I need A8 to be empty and A9 to be =SUM(C4,H4)

Answer (score 0):

You could use - `IF(MOD(ROW(),8)` to identify the 8th row and do a different action i.e make it blank. Without seeing the formula its hard to know how this would effect your increments

If you are needing to have a moving sum to account for the empty spaces - this (or something along these lines) should work:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),8)=0,"",SUM(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()-ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/8,0)),INDIRECT("G"&ROW()-ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/8,0))))
```

Comment: That great, except the formula still increments over the empty cell. If cell A7 has formula =SUM(C3.H3) then I need A8 to be empty and A9 to be =SUM(C4,H4)

Comment: The above, or if every eighth row is empty, you could use `COUNTA(1:ROW())`

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, could you clarify please?

Comment: I misinterpreted your initial question. This comment you made makes it a lot clearer. Perhaps you could add it to your initial question.

Comment: I've tweaked something that you can try. Its rather fiddly.